# jquerymobile large custom select list error on select

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page, which contains a select/options element.  I am also using NativeMenu = false.

When the size of the select list is small enough for it to render all onscreen, there are no problems.

But, when the list is too long, and a ui dialog is required, I get the following error on selecting an item from the list

```
TypeError: fromPage.data(...) is undefined
fromPage.data( "mobile-page" )._trigger( "hide", null, { nextPage: toPage } );
jqueryMobile-1.3.2.js (line 4061)
```

After which, the original page is re-presented, but the Select element is no longer operational.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

#### EDIT #1

I'm generating the selectbox with the following ASP.Net MVC code:

```
<div style="width:55%;float:left;" id="itemMenuArea">
    <select name="itemFilterMenu" id="itemFilterMenu" data-theme="c" data-corners="false" data-mini="true">
        <option value="-1">All Items</option>
        @foreach(var choice in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.EventList){
            <option value="@choice.Value">@choice.Text</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

The output of that looks like this:

```
<div id="itemMenuArea" style="width:55%;float:left;">
    <div class="ui-select">
        <a href="#" role="button" id="itemFilterMenu-button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="itemFilterMenu-menu" data-corners="false" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-mini ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"><span>All Items</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a>

        <select data-mini="true" data-corners="false" data-theme="c" id="itemFilterMenu" name="itemFilterMenu" tabindex="-1">
            <option value="-1">All Items</option>
            <option value="21">BJA</option>
            <option value="8">BonAppetit</option>
            <option value="3">Community Ed</option>
            <option value="15">donations</option>
            <option value="22">Fall Reg</option>
            <option value="2">Food Service</option>
            <option value="18">Group A</option>
            <option value="20">Group B</option>
            <option value="23">Group c</option>
            <option value="24">Group c</option>
            <option value="25">Group c</option>
            <option value="26">Group D</option>
            <option value="27">Group E</option>
            <option value="28">Group F</option>
            <option value="29">Group G</option>
            <option value="30">Group H</option>
            <option value="31">Group I</option>
            <option value="32">Group J</option>
            <option value="33">Group K</option>
            <option value="34">Group L</option>
            <option value="35">Group M</option>
            <option value="36">Group N</option>
            <option value="37">Group O</option>
            <option value="38">Group P</option>
            <option value="39">Group Q</option>
            <option value="40">Group R</option>
            <option value="6">Hastings Test</option>
            <option value="5">Lakeville Test</option>
            <option value="12">Leroy Test</option>
            <option value="13">QIS Test</option>
            <option value="9">St Cloud Test</option>
            <option value="7">Texas Test</option>
            <option value="10">WinSNAP Test</option>
        </select>
        <div style="display: none;"><!-- placeholder for itemFilterMenu-listbox --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT #2

I tried again to build a jsFiddle, but the results are that it seems to work just fine in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/2E88a/8/

#### EDIT #3 ###  Other Libraries

jquery, jqueryui, jquery unobtrusive, jquery validate (standard asp.net mvc setup)
plus modernizr and moment.js

Comment: Could you show some of the code you use to populate the selectbox? Actually, if possible, please provide all of the relevant code parts or (best) - provide a fiddle.

Comment: I've been unsuccessful producing a fiddle...but I can gather some of the other info.

Comment: Are you binding any changes to `mobileinit`? What other libraries are you using?

Comment: only  $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;

Comment: Then it could be a asp.net issue. Are you using single page model (multi html files)? If yes, then this is the problem. JQM can have more than one page in each html file. Dialog is a page. If you use multi-page model (all pages in one file) it should work.

Comment: Yes, our application makes substantial use of partialViews.  This necessitates 'single-pages'.  I'm not sure it can be entirely laid at the feet of asp.net, and I think you might be unnecessarily mixing the 'page' that jqm works with, and the 'page' that asp.net works with. But you're right, it does make it very hard to isolate where the real problem is.  In this case, dialog IS a new page, but its being dynamically added by jquery mobile.  We've got other segments in the code where we make use of the dialog without any issue at all.

Comment: Dialog or popup? If you make that page where you have long selectmenu your homepage or the page you start with, does it work?

Comment: both dialogs and popups.  I moved the generated <select> code to my main page, and it gives no issues there.  So, its definitely an interaction issue with the complicated page we're using it on (an ajax-heavy, multiple-panel shopping cart).  Sadly, I still don't have a clue how to isolate this issue :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43361/discussion-between-omar-and-reidlinden)

Comment: @reidLinden Is this still an open question? Did you find a answer?

Comment: We ended up abandoning our use of JQM, so yea, I guess its not really open anymore... I never found anything satisfactory